# Plotly: Create table with rowname from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plotly

I am trying to create a plotly table with Python Panda Dataframe using package :import plotly.graph_objs as go
I would like to have my panda dataframe rownames as row names in the plotly table. Can this be done
[the table from dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/207Od.png)
i am not able to have the XXX, YYY, etc as column names. Please help.[The table from plotly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GLOq.png)

Comment: Please include a sample data, and also what you precisely did (the code). This will increase the chances of you getting a quick and correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Sushmita *Are* `XXX` and `YYY` in the dataframe that you're trying to put into a table? It doesn't look like that from the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import pandas as pd
    
    df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_usa_states.csv')
    
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
        header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                    fill_color='paleturquoise',
                    align='left'),
        cells=dict(values=[df.Rank, df.State, df.Postal, df.Population],
                   fill_color='lavender',
                   align='left'))
    ])
    
    fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: unlike the other answers this one allows you to change the formatting of individual columns

Answer (score 2):

Install this library to generate image from graph.

```
pip install kaleido
```

Script:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd


fig = ff.create_table(df)
fig.show()
fig.write_image("myimage.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by graph_obj table. 
However, you can create table using plotly following this:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/school_earnings.csv")

    table = ff.create_table(df)
    py.iplot(table, filename='jupyter-table1')
```

From the link: https://plot.ly/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/